# Zeep not parsing the response

Tags: xml, soap, zeep

I have soap response, which is not being parsed with my soap client. Using zeep==2.5.0
zeep.exceptions.XMLParseError: Unexpected element '{url1}SendMessage'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <acb:GetDataResponse xmlns:acb="some url">
      <info>
        <ns4:SendMessageResponse xmlns:ns4="some url1">
          <response>
            <responseInfo>
              <messageId>8a5fd36d-9339-4026-8cb3-3ab69f7c29d1</messageId>
              <responseDate>2018-08-08T13:32:09.704+06:00</responseDate>
              <status>
                <code>SCSS001</code>
                <message>Message has been processed successfully</message>
              </status>
            </responseInfo>
            <responseData>
              <data xmlns:ns2="some url 2" xmlns:ns3="some url 3">
                <ns3:result>
                  <ns3:SomeList>
                    <ns3:IIN>999999222333</ns3:IIN>
                    <ns3:LNAME>ASD</ns3:LNAME>
                    <ns3:FNAME>ASD</ns3:FNAME>
                  </ns3:SomeList>
                </ns3:result>
                <ns3:responseInfo>
                  <ns2:GUID>29344984</ns2:GUID>
                  <ns2:dateMessage>2018-08-08T13:32:09.704+06:00</ns2:dateMessage>
                  <ns2:totalResults>4</ns2:totalResults>
                  <ns2:processingResult>
                    <ns2:code>202</ns2:code>
                    <ns2:description_ru>success</ns2:description_ru>
                    <ns2:description_kz>success</ns2:description_kz>
                    <ns2:isAnswer>true</ns2:isAnswer>
                  </ns2:processingResult>
                </ns3:responseInfo>
              </data>
            </responseData>
          </response>
        </ns4:SendMessageResponse>
      </info>
    </acb:GetDataResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I think that the response structure from the API is incorrect, but cannot find where

Answer (score 0):

Your `WDSL` definition does not contain all needed `XSD`. Request service developer for xsd file containing "some url1" namespace.

Then load:

```
client.wsdl.types.add_document_by_url('/path/to/file.xsd')
```